# Scrape Instagram Web Hashtag Posts

Tags: xpath, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, instagram

I'm trying to scrape the number of posts to a given hashtag (#castles) and populate a Google Sheet cell using ImportXML.

I tried copying the Xpath from Chrome and paste it to the ImportXML parameter in the cell like this:

```
=ImportXML("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/castels/", "//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/span")
```

I saw there is a problem with the quotation marks so I also tried:

```
=ImportXML("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/castels/", "//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/header/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/span")
```

Nevertheless, both return an error.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I am aware of the Xpath to the meta tag description `"//meta[@name='description']/@content"` however I would like to scrape the exact number of posts and not an abbreviated number.

Comment: Would an apps script based solution work or are you looking for it to be accomplished only by using the `=IMPORTXML` function? I figured out the formula but it doesn't work with the caveat of **Result too large**

`=REGEXEXTRACT(ImportXML("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/cats/", "//body/script[1]"),"edge_hashtag_to_media[[:punct:]][[:punct:]][[:punct:]][[:punct:]]count[[:punct:]][[:punct:]](\d+)\,[[:punct:]]page_info[[:punct:]]")`

Edit note: doesn't *work*

Comment: I'm curious... how would an apps script function ?

Comment: Here you go - this of course, is just an example implementation -

function hashCount() {
  var url = 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/cats/';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var regex = /(edge_hashtag_to_media":{"count":)(\d+)(,"page_info":)/gm;
  var count = regex.exec(response)[2];
  Logger.log(count)
}

Comment: returns an empty value :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
function hashCount() {
  var url = 'instagram.com/explore/tags/cats/';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}).getContentText();
  var regex = /(edge_hashtag_to_media":{"count":)(\d+)(,"page_info":)/gm;
  var count = regex.exec(response)[2];
  Logger.log(count);
}
```

**Demo** -

[image: Instagram Hashtag count]

I've added `muteHttpExceptions: true` which was not added in my comment above. Hope this helps.